# React function not working from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone, react-sortable-hoc

I am trying to get a function working which removes an image uploaded using React Dropzone and react-sortable.

I have the dropzone working, and the sort working, but for some reason the function I have on the sortable item which removes that particular item from the array does not work. 
The onClick event does not seem to call the function.

My code is below.

```
 const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value, sortIndex, onRemove}) =>
      <li>{value.name} <a onClick={() => onRemove(sortIndex)}>Remove {value.name}</a></li>
    );

 const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items, onRemove}) => {
    return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((image, index) => (
        <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={image} sortIndex={index} onRemove={onRemove} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});

class renderDropzoneInput extends React.Component {

constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { files: [] }
    this.handleDrop = this.handleDrop.bind(this)
  }

  handleDrop (files) {
    this.setState({
      files
    });
    this.props.input.onChange(files)
  }

  remove (index){
    var array = this.state.files
    array.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({files: array })
    this.props.input.onChange(array)
  }

  onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    this.setState({
      files: arrayMove(this.state.files, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
  };

  render () {
    const {
        input, placeholder,
        meta: {touched, error}
      } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <Dropzone
          {...input}
          name={input.name}
          onDrop={this.handleDrop}
        >
          <div>Drop your images here or click to open file picker</div>
        </Dropzone>
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}


        <SortableList items={this.state.files} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} onRemove={(index) => this.remove(index)} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default renderDropzoneInput
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:  This was caused by react-sortable-hoc swallowing click events.  Setting a `pressDelay` prop on the element allowed the click function to fire.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question, but some people, like me, who still see this issue, might want to read this: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/issues/111#issuecomment-272746004

Issue is that sortable-hoc swallows onClick events as Matt found out. But we can have workarounds by setting `pressDelay` or `distance`.

For me the best option was to set minimum distance for sortable list and it worked nicely

> You can also use the distance prop to set a minimum distance to be dragged before sorting is triggered (for instance, you could set a distance of 1px like so: distance={1})